# Akka subsequent tells

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor

Are messages sent by subsequent `tell` invocations guaranteed to be processed by the actor in the order in which they were sent?

Example:

```scala
actor ! message1
actor ! message2
```

Will `message1` and `message2` be always seen by the actor in the order in which they were sent.

Comment: Yes, but the message could be lost. Please check [message ordering](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/general/message-delivery-reliability.html#discussion-message-ordering) from akka doc.

Comment: I'm aware of the `fire and forget` semantics of `tell`. I wanted to know that if both messages arrive, will they arrive at the order in which they were sent.

Comment: According to the link in the previous comment from Akka docs and from my experience, if they arrive, they will arrive in order. ie, `message1` followed by `message2`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `message1` and `message2` are sent in that order from the same thread, or from the same actor and they are sent to the same actor (and that actor is using a mailbox that does not reorder messages: the default mailbox does not, but one can implement mailboxes which reorder messages, e.g. in order to implement prioritization), `message2` will not be received by the target actor before `message1`.

Thus any of the of these four is possible:

- `message1` is received and then `message2`
- `message1` is received, but `message2` is never received
- `message1` is never received, but `message2` is
- neither `message1` nor `message2` is ever received

Note that there is no guarantee that two message sends to different actors will be received in any particular order.  There is also no guarantee regarding the ordering of message sends from two different actors (or if outside of any actor (e.g. in a `Future` callback or the main method), a different thread)).

Comment: It's worth noting that in the special case where sender and recipient are in the same `ActorSystem`, there is a slightly stronger guarantee in practice, subject to the same constraints around mailbox type: `message2` will not be received unless `message1` is (in other words, the third ordering is impossible).  Depending on this everywhere in an application constrains you to deploying in a single `ActorSystem` (by extension, a single OS process), but it's something that definitely has its place.